# Starting ethpool / ethermine using ethminer on ubuntu

Tags: ethminer

I am trying the below and they don't work for me :

`ethminer --farm-recheck 200 -G -F eu1.ethermine.org:4444/0x<Your_Ethereum_Address>.<RigName`>

`ethminer --farm-recheck 200 -G -F eu1.ethpool.org:3333/0x<Your_Ethereum_Address>.<RigName`>

And I am getting `JSON RPC Error - Probably cannot connect`

Why is that? Also what is the -S argument ( something about Stratum ?? what is that?) This doesn't work as well.

Comment: If you are on Ethereum, I have no idea why you are talkign about stratumn, but here is their white paper if you want to know more : https://proofofprocess.org

Answer (score 2):

If you're using ethermine, follow their guide for the correct commandline.  That is because ethermine is configured as stratum.

```
ethminer --farm-recheck 200 -G -S eu1.ethermine.org:4444 -FS us1.ethermine.org:4444 -O <Your_Ethereum_Address>.<RigName>
```

There are quite a number of ethminer builds, what I did was to install cpp-ethereum via PPA and then download the latest binary from https://github.com/ethereum-mining/ethminer and overwrote the existing one.

Works like a charm!